# How to pivot the pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a pandas df in the following format

```
LABEL,DATE,VALUE
A,2005-03-31,1
A,2006-03-31,2
A,2007-03-31,3
A,2008-03-31,4
B,2005-03-31,5
B,2006-03-31,6
B,2007-03-31,7
B,2008-03-31,8
```

I want to convert it into the following format

```
DATE
LABEL 2005-03-31, 2006-03-31, 2007-03-31, 2008-03-31  
A           1   ,    2      ,     3     ,     4
B           5   ,    6      ,     7     ,     8
```

I tried the following but getting different exceptions

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[1])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df['DATE'], columns=df['LABEL'],values='VALUE')
-- not working
df.set_index([df['DATE'], df['LABEL']]).VALUE.unstack()
-- not working Error - ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['LABEL', 'DATE']).VALUE.unstack()
print (df)

DATE   2005-03-31  2006-03-31  2007-03-31  2008-03-31
LABEL                                                
A               1           2           3           4
B               5           6           7           8
```

If:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means there are duplicates in pairs `LABEL` and `DATE`, so necessary aggregation:

```
#changed sample data
print (df)
  LABEL        DATE  VALUE
0     A  2005-03-31      1 <-duplicate A, 2005-03-31
1     A  2005-03-31      2 <-duplicate A, 2005-03-31
2     A  2007-03-31      3
3     A  2008-03-31      4
4     B  2005-03-31      5
5     B  2006-03-31      6
6     B  2007-03-31      7
7     B  2008-03-31      8

df1 = df.groupby(['LABEL', 'DATE']).VALUE.mean().unstack()
print (df1)
DATE   2005-03-31  2006-03-31  2007-03-31  2008-03-31
LABEL                                                
A             1.5         NaN         3.0         4.0 <- (1+2)/2=1.5 (mean)
B             5.0         6.0         7.0         8.0
```

For replace `NaN`s to `0` add parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['LABEL', 'DATE']).VALUE.mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
DATE   2005-03-31  2006-03-31  2007-03-31  2008-03-31
LABEL                                                
A             1.5         0.0         3.0         4.0
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='LABEL', columns='DATE', values='VALUE', fill_value=0)
```

Error:

> pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

means no numeric values.

```
df['VALUE'] = pd.to_numeric(df['VALUE'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Finally this seems to have worked df = df.groupby(['LABEL', 'DATE']).VALUE.sum().unstack()

Comment: @Shakti Or `df.pivot_table(index='LABEL', columns='DATE', values='VALUE')`

Comment: This finally worked for me, there were some blanks which was causing issue in the actual file . df['VALUE'] = pd.to_numeric(df['VALUE'], errors='coerce')
    df = df.groupby(['DATE', 'LABEL']).VALUE.sum().unstack()

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Shakti - do you need replace blanks by `0` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try `pivot` , try to change swap `index` and `columns` assignment

```
df.pivot(*df.columns)
Out[495]: 
DATE   2005-03-31  2006-03-31  2007-03-31  2008-03-31
LABEL                                                
A               1           2           3           4
B               5           6           7           8
```

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @Shakti which means your sample data can not reproduced your problem .

Answer (score 0):

you need [pd.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html),

```
 pd.pivot_table(df,index='LABEL',columns='DATE',values='VALUE')
```